# How to add smack as a library project for android in eclipse?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I want to add **`org.jivesoftware.smack`** as a library project in my android app, not as jar in **`Eclipse`**. I am trying to customize the library for custom packets(`XMPP Message and Packet`) but m not able to do it until i have the complete source code of smack.

Comment: Create a new project on Eclipse and import https://github.com/rtreffer/smack/tree/master/source/org/jivesoftware/smack

Comment: I have added this,,,but where i can find the missing imports and jars...